# How to disconnect SIM from network on schedule

Tags: mobile-data, sim-card, mobile-network, dual-sim

I have a 2-SIM phone and need to be able to unregister one of the SIMs from the network each Friday from 16:30 to 20:00. The reason is that this SIM is a duplicate of another SIM which my friends use to stream a series of lectures every Friday. The SIMs have unlimited data, so I want to use my copy for data during the rest of the week.

Both of the SIMs cannot be connected to the network at the same time because then the behavior is unpredictable and we do not want any interruptions in the stream. I could physically pull the SIM out every Friday, but I might forget and it's a hassle to open the phone every time.

**Is there a way to schedule a disconnection of the SIM from the carrier network on schedule?**

(There may be an app for that, but I couldn't find one. I am a software developer, so I can even write my own if there is some way to accomplish this, but I'm not sure whether there is an API that would allow this. I have a Fairphone 3, so I can even root the phone as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a community favorite: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)! It is very straightforward to set up a profile to exist that is triggered based on a day of the week and time, as you specified.

Disabling the SIM appears to be possible, and will require either:

1. A rooted phone
2. Enabling ADB Wifi each time you reboot your phone

Assuming you've done one of those, there's an [excellent video demonstrating this task setup here on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsCkyuz-siQ).

The steps are as follows:

- Create a new Profile based on "Day"
- Change "Month Day" to "Week Day" and select Friday
- Click the back button at the top right
- Select "New Task" and give it a title
- Click the "+" button to add an action and search for ADB Wifi
- In the "Command" line, paste the following: `phone.setSimPowerStateForSlot(0,0)` where the first zero is the SIM number (change to '1' to disable the second sim) and the second zero is the power (0 for off, 1 for on)
- Go back and add an exit task to turn it back on with the same ADB Wifi command entered as `phone.setSimPowerStateForSlot(0,1)`
- Go back to the profiles screen and long-press on the "Fri" and choose "Add"
- Choose "Time" and set the time you'd like the SIM to be disabled

Comment: Is there any open source alternative? I neither have nor plan to have a Google account and while I would happily pay a few bucks for Tasker, it's not possible without Google.

Comment: The creator has listed some older versions for download on their website (https://tasker.joaoapps.com/download.html) and it appears the current version is available from the creator via APK Mirror (https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/joaomgcd/tasker/), but as always, be careful with installing apps downloaded outside the Play Store.